# Postgresql trigger on user logon

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out of a way of knowing as soon as a user logs into a Postgres database.  Is there a way to define a trigger to fire when a user logs into the DB?  Or is there a table or a system view that gets updated whenever anyone logs into the DB?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. The only "view" that gets updated is `pg_stat_activity` which reflects all current connections. But you would need to poll that with an extremely high frequency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything at the SQL level which can identify a logon event (i.e. no view you can query, and no trigger you can create).

You can, however, write a server-side module (in C) which intercepts logon events via the [`ClientAuthentication_hook`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/libpq/auth.h). This hook is invoked after the server has attempted to authenticate a user, but before it has sent its response.

There is a worked example of a `ClientAuthentication_hook` on the [Postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/e/e3/Hooks_in_postgresql.pdf). You can also find a couple of examples of this hook in action within Postgres' own [contrib modules](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/search?q=ClientAuthentication_hook+path%3Acontrib).

Answer (score 4):

[login_hook](https://github.com/splendiddata/login_hook)

> Postgres database extension to execute som code on user login,
>   comparable to Oracle's after logon trigger.