# How to update a timestamp column whilst making a select to another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jooq

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1
(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    last_login TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2
(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    t1_id UUID NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),

    CONSTRAINT ids
        FOREIGN KEY (t1_id)
            REFERENCES t1 (id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION

);
```

and I want to select a row from *t2* and update the *last_login* timestamp of the corresponding *t1* id in the t1 table.

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Comment: You need to do this at the application level.  I don't think any database supports "triggers" based on `select` queries.

Comment: A SELECT statement cannot update data. However, it sounds like you want to have an AFTER LOGIN trigger, which is how I'd implement this in Oracle. Apparently Postgresql does not support login triggers, but has something similar - [see this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104368/postgresql-trigger-on-user-logon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't both `UPDATE` and `SELECT` in the same SQL operation. You have some options though:

1. Do it at the application level - update the login, then select the data
2. Do it as a SPROC / function that you can execute where both operations are executed in sequence with possible rollback if needed
3. Use triggers to update logins independently
4. Combine the tables to simplify things if they're always 1 to 1 anyway

Comment: You would use a function in Postgres if you want to return a result set, not a stored procedure