# Create read-only temporary table when user connects

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have a function or stored procedure that runs when a specific user connects to a PSQL database.

More specifically, I would like for a Temporary table to be created when the that user logs in and the user have only read access to that temporary table and nothing else.

Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

**User Setup**

```
CREATE ROLE test_user WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'test_pw' 
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE testDB TO test_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA testschemaTO test_user;
GRANT SELECT ON temp_table TO test_user;  -- when can I do this?
```

**Temp table**

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT id
     , name
     , flag
FROM   some_table
WHERE  colour LIKE '%blue%'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: From what I'm gathering about the documentation in the section ["Compatibility > Temporary Tables"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-COMPATIBILITY), when a new postgres session/connection is made, no temporary table effectively exists for that session and the subsequent created temporary tables only exist for that session. The documentation is not completely clear on that though, so I might be wrong. From the use-case you're describing, wouldn't a view make more sense, as if it's only read only and created from a select it should have similar results

Comment: The problem I have is that I am trying to connect with a 3rd party app that can only connect to tables.

Comment: This may be a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628437/2232127 but that solutions executes the code always as the user who's logging in. Though I'm intrigued why that 3rd party app can't use views. Maybe if you could elaborate on your use-case, a better solution may be possible?